# Import TranslateModule in Ionic

Tags: javascript, ionic-framework, angular-translate

I have a ionic app and use ngx-translate to translate it.

I use in my home and import it in home.module.ts

```
imports: [
    IonicPageModule.forChild(HomePage),
    TranslateModule.forChild({
      loader: {
        provide: TranslateLoader,
        useFactory: (createTranslateLoader),
        deps: [HttpClient]
      }
    })
  ],
```

But when I push in the navController other page, if i use:

```
{{ 'SOME_STRING' | translate }}
```

I have this error

```
Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Template parse errors:
The pipe 'translate' could not be found
```

I can solve it importing the TranlateModule too in the other page, but I have a lot of pages and it's not so useful.

I thought this

```
TranslateModule.forChild
```

'pass' this Module to all the pages in the pile,

Is it not? Have I to import the TranslateModule in all the pages then use the Translate pipe?

Thanks

Comment: Your project contains lazy loading? Or is your project contains multiple modules?

Comment: I have only the app,module (and the ones create when I create a page with the cli).... The translate only works in the pages I declare in the declarations, but when I try to add another say me: Error: Type AskingPage is part of the declarations of 2 modules:

Comment: Hope my answer will help you : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50403437/cant-resolve-all-parameters-for-translateservice-object-objec/50405410#50405410

Answer (score 0):

```
import {NgModule} from '@angular/core';
import {BrowserModule} from '@angular/platform-browser';
import {HttpClientModule, HttpClient} from '@angular/common/http';
import {TranslateModule, TranslateLoader} from '@ngx-translate/core';
import {TranslateHttpLoader} from '@ngx-translate/http-loader';
import {AppComponent} from './app';

// AoT requires an exported function for factories
export function HttpLoaderFactory(http: HttpClient) {
   return new TranslateHttpLoader(http, './assets/i18n/', '.json');
}

@NgModule({
    imports: [
        BrowserModule,
        HttpClientModule,
        TranslateModule.forRoot({
            loader: {
                provide: TranslateLoader,
                useFactory: HttpLoaderFactory,
                deps: [HttpClient]
            }
        })
    ],
    bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Try this, you can find more explanation here : [Doc](https://github.com/ngx-translate/core)

Comment: I remove the modules for home and login pages and import this pages (are both root) in the declaration of the app.module... but to do it I have to delete the login.module and the home.module.. if not I have an error `Error: Type homePage is part of the declarations of 2 modules:` But still don't work in the pages in the pile of both :-(